# Boost::numeric::ublas::prod performance became slower moving from boost 1.51 to boost 1.60

Tags: boost

I am using intel icpc compiler and using Boost::numeric::ublas::prod method through ICC 13.1/mkl/include/mkl_boost_ublas_matrix_prod.hpp header. Moving from boost 1.51 to boost 1.60 the performance become slower by around 30 times. I did not do any other changes other than moving to boost 1.60.
Any idea why this is happening? Let me know if any suggestions.

Using following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <mkl_boost_ublas_matrix_prod.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
int main()
{



    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> A(643, 13503);
       boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> B(13503, 413);
       boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> C(643, 413);

       for (int i = 0; i < A.size1(); ++i)
          for (int j = 0; j < A.size2(); ++j)
            A(i,j) = i+j;

       for (int i = 0; i < B.size1(); ++i)
          for (int j = 0; j < B.size2(); ++j)
            B(i,j) = i+j;
       std::cout << "starting multiplication" << std::endl;
       boost::timer t;
       noalias(C) = prod(A,B);
       //B = prod(A,B);

       std::cout << "ublas: " << t.elapsed() << std::endl;

 }
```

Comment: I suggest making a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people diagnose this issue

Comment: I suggest asking on the boost mailing list.  They will almost certainly need a [mcve] to investigate.

Comment: I created one example, but unfortunately not able to reproduce the issue with the example code. :-( Will check myself first.